# wx.TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT has no effect?

Tags: python, wxpython

I created a TreeListCtrl in wxPython like following.

```
self.tree = wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl(self, style =
                                           wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE
                                           | wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT | wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT | wx.TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
```

As you see i set wx.TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT but there is no effect. All the rows have same height.

How can i change the row height in TreeListCtrl.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wx.TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT` applies to wx.TreeCntrl not wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl, read http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl-class.html to see what that tree cntrl can do

If you see the doc or code for wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl it derives from wx.Control, so it seems to be a a generic implementation of TreeCtrl with extra columns but doesn't seem to inherit from wxTreeCntrl

Comment: Isn't wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl inheriting functionality from wx.TreeCtrl? Or should i have to customize the wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl class?